# Como pegar valor da regra CSS aplicado por uma classe no JS (teste unitário)

Tags: javascript, html, react, testes-de-unidade

Estou escrevendo testes para um componente web, o mesmo tem um dinâmica de troca de cores e eu gostaria de testar se essa cor foi trocada.

Durante a escrita dos testes, tenho acesso a DOM para capturar os elementos com `querySelector`, onde efetuo a query `const el = document.querySelector('[data-testid="price"]')`, para selecionar a tag span.

Porem ao testa `el.style.color` para saber se a cor é igual a `"#000"`, o mesmo me retorna
uma string vazia (`""`), aparentemente as regras aplicadas por classe não alimentam a propriedade style do componente no JS. Há alguma forma de validar essa regra da classe ?

Class css

```
.gCPFyd {
    color: #000;
    font: 16px Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span data-testid="price" class="sc-hBUSln gCPFyd">R$ 0,00</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está pegando as propriedades de estilo do elemento com `element.style` e não os estilos da classe dele.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[data-testid="price"]'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);

console.log(style.color);

// para propriedades com hífen no nome, pode-se usar das duas
// opções abaixo

console.log(style.fontSize); 
console.log(style["font-size"]);
```

```css
.minha-classe {
    color: limegreen;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<span data-testid="price" class="minha-classe">R$ 0,00</span>
```

A função `window.getComputedStyle()` obtém os estilos computados no elemento, ou seja, aqueles que as classes também aplicam. A propriedade `element.style` funciona apenas para os estilos aplicados inline no elemento com `style="color: #000"`.

---

- [Documentação do `getComputedStyle()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
- [Documentação da propriedade `style`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função `getComputedStyle`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
const el = document.querySelector('[data-testid="price"]')
const style = getComputedStyle(el)
```